Why I am getting error from windows deployment toolkit?
I am using oracle Virtual Box 7.1.4
I have windows server 2022 that is part of the domain and it is having Microsoft Deployment Toolkit and Windows Deployment Services. I have followed a tutorial online and everything is fine until I created a new oracle VM to load from network boot (to take the image of 64bit windows 11 image) and choose the image. At the end of the process it is giving me
this error:

The PXE server processed a request from a client of architecture x86.
However there were no boot images installed for this architecture.
PXE clients of this architecture will not be able to complete the boot
process successfully.  To resolve this problem, add at least one boot
image for this architecture.

